# mapview, replace/remove a map pin

Tags: android, canvas, icons, android-mapview

This part of code takes some coordinates and draws a tag icon in the map.

```
private void drawMapLocations(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView) {
    Iterator<MapTagLocation> iterator = mapTab.getMapLocations().iterator();
    Point screenCoords = new Point();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        MapTagLocation location = iterator.next();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(location.getPoint(), screenCoords);
        canvas.drawBitmap(tagIcon, screenCoords.x - tagIcon.getWidth() / 2, screenCoords.y - tagIcon.getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a method that removes or replace a specific tag in the map. Is there any way?

*The tagIcon is a Bitmap.

Comment: Couldn't you simply remove a `MapTagLocation` using `iterator.remove`? Then next time the map is drawn it will not be in the list

Comment: i want to remove the pin while the app is running. how i can do that with the iterator remove?